# ArcGIS Pro zoom to previous extent

Tags: arcgis-pro, extents, zoom

I am getting started with ArcGIS Pro 2.9 and I want to know how to zoom to previous extent preferably using a button as in ArcMap, since I am working on a foreign laptop and the keyboard configuration is not yet optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would strongly recommend you upgrade ArcGIS Pro if you can as there is lots of new functionality and bug fixes since the old version of 2.9.

Short cut keys are found at the [ArcGIS Pro keyboard shortcuts](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/arcgis-pro-keyboard-shortcuts.htm) help page and it is the `<` key to go to previous extent.

Comment: Thanks I work in a computer that connects remotely to the provider of ArcGis Pro, so I can not upgrade the version, and for similar reasons I have problems with my keyboard (language problems) so I can not apply key combinations with > <

Answer (score 0):

I found it, in the upper menu, click on Customize Ribbon, select More commands and find Previous Extent.